# applying css to nth child words

Tags: javascript, jquery

An interesting little problem...

Trying to loop through the children of a paragraph (words) and color them, one by one.

Here's a hard coded working version with words in separate elements:
http://jsfiddle.net/JjRHT/25/

using

```
window.setInterval(function(){
$(".item:nth-child(1)").css("color", "#FFFFFF");
}, 1000);
```

just to show what I'm attempting...obviously not the way to go!

so - can I select each child of a paragraph? and how do I do the loop properly - with a small delay...

steven

edit:

I found a jquery [plugin](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js) that splits text into words nicely ready for css:

```
<p class="word_split">Don't break my heart.</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".word_split").lettering('words');
});
</script>
```

Which will generate:

```
<p class="word_split">
  <span class="word1">Don't</span>
  <span class="word2">break</span>
  <span class="word3">my</span>
  <span class="word4">heart.</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you can't apply styles to words of a paragraph.

If you want to color words (and not the whole element), you'll have to extract the words from the paragraph.

This cuts the paragraph in two parts, and gives a different color to each part :

```
var tokens = $paragraph.text().split(' ');
var i=0;
window.setInterval(function(){
       i = (i+1)%tokens.length;
       $paragraph.html( '<span class=onecolor>'+tokens.slice(0, i).join(' ')+'</span>'
           + ' <span class=othercolor>'+tokens.slice(i, tokens.length).join(' ')+'</span>');
}, 1000);​
```

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/CcBLr/1/

---

EDIT :

Supposing you want to make specific things on your words (as you say, different delays for example), you could do this for the preparation :

```
var tokens = $paragraph.text().split(' ');
var spans = tokens.map(function(t){return '<span>'+t+'</span>'});
$paragraph.html(spans.join(' '));
var $words = $paragraph.children('span');
```

`$words` is now a collection of the words of the paragraph but you may apply styles on them. for example with this :

```
$words.each(function(){
   var $word = $(this);
   setTimeout(
   ...
```

Comment: thanks - an interesting method - but I'd need the current word on its own as the delay will be variable according to the word (length, a fullstop etc)

Comment: @anatole why use a plugin when you do it in 2 lines (3 lines here because I decomposed for clarity) ?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/JjRHT/38/

here this is with a delay

**edit**:
Updated Version
http://jsfiddle.net/JjRHT/38/

Answer (score 0):

With a small delay, like you requested:

```
var delay = 300; // delay in milliseconds

$(".item").children().each(function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).css("color", "#FFFFFF");
    }, index*delay);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loop as you are calling just on [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) as setInterval is self recall the function every time, all what you need is to increase the modifier.

check this http://jsfiddle.net/JjRHT/39/

Answer (score 0):

var time= 300;

$('.item').each(function(index) {

window.setInterval(function(){$(".item:nth-child("+(index+1)+")").css("color", "#FFFFFF");}, time*index);
});